# How to tell if Oracle Streams is installed?

Tags: java, database, oracle, jms, oracle-streams

I am just setting up a test project using Oracle Streams.

My first problem is, is there something I need to install first?  How can I tell if Oracle Streams is installed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Streams is automatically included in Oracle 9.2 Enterprise Edition and up.  You may need to take additional steps to configure your instance to use Streams, however.  This presentation covers a lot of the steps of configuration:  http://www.scribd.com/doc/123217/Oracle-Streams-Step-by-Step-PPT

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure if it was included or not.  But I really don't like that PPT presentation, it's not a simple enough example for me using Streams for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

What version of oracle?   It comes installed by default from at least 10g.